# PDF: Showing an invisible digital signature

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, acrobat

I have a digitally signed a PDF using JsignPDF. I had visible signature selected, however when I open the PDF in acrobat, the signature is invisible. Is there any way to show the signature?

The signature is verified and you can click on the signature, acrobat has it as invisible and I would like to show it.

Comment: Without you providing (a link to) the actual PDF showing the described problem, very likely nobody will be able to help you...